# Visio class diagram

Tags: visio, class-diagram

I'm using Visio class diagram.

1. Is there a way to automatically layout the elements on the canvas?
2. I want to group a few classes under some square to visually show that they belong to the same package. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically layout the elements on the canvas?

Yes. Under the `Shape` menu, click `Lay Out Shapes`.

> I want to group a few classes under some square to visually show that they belong to the same package. How to do it?

Just draw a square around the items in question, then `Send To Back` so that the square is in the background rather than the foreground.

Comment: 2. how do I draw a square in UML mode?

Comment: There is a drawing tool called "Rectangle".

Answer (score 1):

1. The shape menu has the option "Layout Shapes"
2. Add a rectangle, send it to back. Then layout and align the shapes above the rectangle, then select the shapes and the rectangle and hit Ctrl-G to group them.